# NSURL URLWithString: giving nil

Tags: iphone, nsurl

Please see the below code :

```
UIImage *image;
NSString *str = [[[Data getInstance]arrPic]objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
NSLog(str);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

**str** is giving me `http://MyDomain/Pics\\1.png` but **url** is giving me **nil**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just try using this,

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 9.0.

Comment: this breaks the URL if there's a # in it by converting the # to %2

Comment: try this :  [string urlEncodeUsingNSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, the `URLWithString:` methods takes a *well-formed* URL string :

> This method expects URLString to contain any necessary percent escape codes, which are ‘:’, ‘/’, ‘%’, ‘#’, ‘;’, and ‘@’. Note that ‘%’ escapes are translated via UTF-8.

I suggest you retry the same using `NSString`'s `(NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` method before.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS9, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated. To safely escape a URL string, use:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *alphaNumSymbols = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"~!@#$&*()-_+=[]:;',/?."];
[alphaNumSymbols formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];

str = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:alphaNumSymbols];
```

This creates sets of characters to keep as is and asks everything outside of these CharacterSets to be converted to %percent encoded values.